# Implementing a mathematical formula in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a math problem in Python which returns the count of numbers divisible by **X** between **M** and **N**, where **M <= N**.

I have written the below code:

```
result_list = []

for _ in range(int(raw_input())):
  a, b, m = map(int,raw_input().split())
  counter = a
  result = 0

  if a % m == 0:
    while counter <= b:
      result += 1
      counter += m
  else:
    for e in range(a, b + 1):
      if e % m == 0:
        while counter <= b:
          result += 1
          counter += m
        break

  result_list.append(result)

for e in result_list:
  print (e)
```

However, when I run it, I'm not able to get the result I need.
It would be great to get some help on solving this problem.

Comment: What do you mean you're not able to get the result you need?

Comment: Please see [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Please be clear with what your problem actually is. Is this even your code?

Comment: The first input is for the loop. The number of inputs. The next input is a list of space separated integers in the format `M, N, X`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is a little confusing and seems to have some fundamental flaws. Here is how I would do it if I was doing the challenge:

```
for _ in range(int(raw_input())):
    m, n, x = map(int, raw_input().split())
    print [i%x==0 for i in range(m,n)].count(True))
```

I think the first 2 lines are pretty clear. Important thing from the first 2 lines: name your variables clearly. Don't use a, b, x for inputs you call m, n, x.

I will split up the third line to show what I am doing. The smallest part is

```
range(m,n)
```

This returns a list consisting of every number in that range, not including n, so if you want to go up to a certain number k, n should equal k+1. For example, if m = 3, n = 10 and x = 20, the list will be

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Next is the list comprehension

```
[i%x==0 for i in range(m,n)]
```

It loops over the range m, n, and tests if each number is divisible by x in that range. If the the number is divisible by s, it will put True, if it isn't divisible it will put False. In the example above, it would give:

```
[False, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

As you can see, the second and third elements are True and True, because i is equal to 4 and 5 respectively for those spots on the list.

now that we have our list full of booleans we map the ones that are true with

```
[x%i==0 for i in range(m,n)].count(True))
```

and print the answer.

If you wanted a list instead you could append to a list instead of printing.

Comment: Thanks, Sam! I understand your logic, but still am not getting the answer I need. For example, if m = 2, n = 6, and x = 2, the answer would have to be 3 since there are 3 numbers between 2 and 6 that are divisible by 2: [2, 4, 6]. However, this program returns 1.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were looking for. I have edited my comment to reflect that.